# NSPanel not hiding when focus is lost

Tags: swift, nswindow, nspanel

I am trying to create a window like Spotlight.
As in Spotlight it should hide when the background is clicked. I tried doing it unsuccessfully with NSWindow but I was lead to believe using NSPanel instead would solve the problem.
However, even when using NSPanel the window does not hide.
Here is the code I'm using.

```
let panel = NSPanel(contentRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200), styleMask: [.titled, .nonactivatingPanel], backing: .buffered, defer: true)
panel.level = .mainMenu
panel.collectionBehavior = [.canJoinAllSpaces, .fullScreenAuxiliary]
panel.orderFrontRegardless()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to used window level (`.mainMenu` which is above all windows), so you need to hide it explicitly via delegate methods

so assuming you create window/panel in your controller, make that controller a delegate of window

```
panel.delegate = self
```

and implement something like

```
extension ViewController { // << your controller class here
   func windowDidResignKey(_ notification: Notification) {
       if let panel = notification.object as? NSWindow {
          panel.close()
       }
   }
}
```